# Renaming a file to name of file that already exists

Tags: c++

i am renaming file for example `file1.txt` to `"newFile.txt"` but when the code runs for the next time. the file `newFile.txt` already exists so the newly file created whos name is `"file1.txt"` doesn't renamed to `"newFile.txt"`

what i want is if the `"newFile.txt"` already exists renaming `"file1.txt"` should overwrite the `"file1.txt"` is it possible ??

Here goes my code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char data[100];

    fstream outfile;
    outfile.open("afile.dat" , ios::out );

    cout << "Writing to the file" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin.getline(data, 100);

    outfile << data << endl;

    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> data;
    cin.ignore();

    // again write inputted data into the file.
    outfile << data << endl;

    cout << "Reading from the file" << endl;

    outfile >> data;
    cout << data << endl;

    outfile >> data;
    cout << data << endl;
    outfile.close();

   // this is how i am renaming
    std::rename("afile.dat" , "file2.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) it first?

Comment: From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename): _"If new_filename exists, the behavior is implementation-defined."_.

Comment: good idea @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Note that if you remove and rename - there's a chance that something could jump in and create the file between your 2 calls.  If you wanted to do it with a 100% success rate I think you'd have to copy the file manually with streams... but I'd bet in this case a remove will do jsut fine

Comment: i was just practicing file system nothing else its not any kinda project 
 or anything @UKMonkey.. BTW i cound't understand what could happen.. i mean we can check if file exists then remove it and rename a file to the file name we wanted isn't that it ???

Comment: @QaMarALi   your program deletes the file -> Other program jumps in and creates the file again -> your program tries to move the file.  Move fails because the file exists.

Comment: What you want to research is "race conditions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works and renames a file only once.

The second time you run your program, file `banana.txt` already exist in that directory and function `std::rename("afile.dat" , "banana.txt");` returns an error code.

So you need to check if a file with the new filename is already exists or handle an error after function `std::rename`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the `<filesystem>` library - you can check it with `std::filesystem::exists()` from the `<filesystem>` header and copy the contents of the old file to the new file with copy option `update_existing`. Then you can remove the old file, effectively doing what you're looking to do.
It'd look like so:

```
if(outFile.is_open()) {
    outFile.close();
}
if( std::filesystem::exists( newFile ) ) {
// this can be on the same line, just making a var for readability
    auto copyOption{std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing};    
    std::filesystem::copy_file( oldFile, newFile, copyOption);
    std::filesystem::remove( oldFile );
// OR if you don't care what was in the old file anyways, 
// ignore the previous three lines above and just remove it
std::remove(oldFile);
} else {
  std::filesystem::rename( oldFile, newFile );
}
outFile.open(newFile);
```

There ARE other ways to do this, but I find this to be a very easy approach in my subjective opinion (if performance of file close/open is acceptable for your case).

Answer (score -2):

why not output contents of new file to another file, then delete the original file already there and ren the new file to original name

cat newfile > newfile1
del original file
ren newfile1 to original file name ... i do this all the  time ... i must be missing something using all that code you are using to do it

Comment: why are the line returns removed when posting .... my comment is confusing ... i try again and see if line breaks are again removed ... why does comment post pressing return so i can't put stuff on a separate line

Comment: Find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help